# Is listening to women sing haram in Islam?

Tags: halal-haram, singing

For a man, is listening to women sing haram (a sin) in Islam? What proof do you have of this?

Comment: well you asked the question. so you should first check the source from where you got this info.

Comment: I heard this from mostly idle chat around, therefore, I don't know if this has any solid source. But it makes sense to some extent, because it may arise lust in men?

Comment: nope there are many naats sung by women in praise of Allah, does that arouse lust in you?

Comment: No, but how about modern pop music. There are some songs that even sound like made with the purpose of arosing lust in men.

Comment: @yasar11732: It's totally Haraam, no matter what the woman is singing about. A voice of a woman singing certainly provokes lust of men.

Comment: @Gigili well if you dont know music overall is forbidden in islam so the question of listening to pop music does not arise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Al-Nawawi said in his book al-Adhkaar (p. 407):
>
> Our companions said: Women greeting women is like men greeting to men.
>   But when it comes to women greeting men, if the woman is the man's
>   wife, or his concubine, or one of his mahrams, then it is like him
>   speaking to another man; it is mustahabb for either of them to
>   initiate the greeting of salaam and the other is obliged to return the
>   greeting. But if the woman is a stranger (non-mahram), if she is
>   beautiful and there is the fear that he may be tempted by her, then
>   the man should not greet her with salaam, and if he does then it is
>   not permissible for her to reply; she should not initiate the greeting
>   of salaam either, and if she does, she does not deserve a response. If
>   he responds then this is makrooh.

[Check the link too](http://forums.islamicawakening.com/f30/ruling-greeting-women-salaam-returning-their-greeting-38736/)

Its not even permissible to greet Ghair Mehram in certain conditions then how its possible listening to her songs would be ok? Which itself is haram in view of Scholars

check teh above link it has lots of references hope will help

Comment: You should add some direct textual evidence from Quran and Hadith. Moreover, [the hadith about the songs of Buath](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/63/157) apparently goes against your conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

yes it is haraam, it is not even makrooh. A woman's voice is her awra - part of her that shouldnt be revealed to men. After the prophet PBUH died, when his companions used to go to Aisha (his wife) for hadeeth, even behind curtains or closed doors she used to put her finger in her mouth to dusguise her voice. On the day of judgment, melted lead will be poured down the ears of those men who listened to signing women. Also there are many hadeeth regarding this, such as one when the prophet PBUH said that one of the signs of judgment day is the increase of singing and dancing women, and in those times expect the earth to swallow them or their transforming into animals. So unless she is his wife, then yes it is haraam for a man to listen to signing women

Comment: Please improve your answer and add references (preferably online) for the hadiths your quoted (and may be their level of authenticity).

Comment: What about listening naat by women?

Comment: Listening to a women’s voice is awrah? So when communicating for maybe purchasing food or at a workplace if need be she reveals her awrah?

Answer (score -2):

Singing is different from being sexy so please don't mix these two things together!
I believe that singing for women is not haram as long as they don't behave sexually and they keep their modesty...and also the songs do not encourage people to do harams like drinking and having sex and that kind of stuff!
so there should be no difference between men and women!

Comment: At first place Music is considered Haram. And more over, women are not supposed to recite even Qur'an aloud. Please support ur answer and also try to do a bit research before answering.

Comment: yes we can mix the two together, as "being sexy" and "singing" both mean the women is exposing herself, which in one way or another provokes lust in men, so please know what you are talking about before you speak. I personally love singing, but dont sing in front of guys or where i know i will be heard by one.

Comment: @Ayli It will be good if you could support your answer with "religious" arguments which generally consist of Quranic verses and authentic hadiths.